# Why is ok_or a suitable replacement for let-else when used on an Option?

Tags: rust

In the [let-else RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html), it states:

> let-else is particularly useful when dealing with enums which are not Option/Result, and as such do not have access to e.g. ok_or().

This confused me, because I thought the main upside of let-else was to enable early returns in order to keep code un-nested. Specifically, it allows for unpacking an enum (among other types) and afterwards assuming it was successful, since the unsuccessful case is handled by a known diverging block.

However, ok_or converts from an Option to a Result, which means you’d still need to perform a pattern match, let-else, if-let, or similar to retrieve the contained value.

So how is ok_or a replacement for let-else, and why wouldn’t I want to use let-else for Options?

Comment: `ok_or` is not a replacement for `let … else` in the general case, but in the case of a function returning `Result`, then `let foo = bar.ok_or (err)?;` is equivalent to `let Some (foo) = bar else { return err; }`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what they were referring to when they wrote it but `ok_or` and `ok` allow you to use `?` in contexts that don't return the type you have, eg in a function that returns `Result<Foo, Error>`

```
fn foo() -> Result<Foo, Error> {
    let bar = fn_that_gets_opt().ok_or(Error::Missing)?;
    // ...use bar without unwrapping
}
```

Equivalently, in a function that returns `Option<Foo>`

```
fn foo() -> Option<Foo> {
    let bar = fn_that_gets_result().ok()?;
    // ...use bar without unwrapping
}
```